# C# Trying to insert into Access, code works but if I add two new parameters it doesn't?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, insert, oledb

I have this working query:

```
"Insert INTO ACTB (ID, FirstName, LastName, GrossIncome, LessTNT, TaxableIncomeCE, TaxableIncomePE, GrossTaxableIncome, LessTE, LessPPH, NetTax, TaxDue, HeldTaxCE, HeldTaxPE, TotalTax, TIN) " +
"VALUES(@ID, @First, @Last, @Gross, @LessTNT, @TCI, @ADDTI, @GTI, @LessTE, @LessPPH, @LessNTI, @TD, @TWCE, @TWPE, @TATW, @TIN)";
```

Not sure how to format that better. Anyways, this works along with the whole command execute thing. Now I've updated the requirements of my program and added two extra fields, say From, and To.

```
"Insert INTO ACTB (ID, FirstName, LastName, GrossIncome, LessTNT, TaxableIncomeCE, TaxableIncomePE, GrossTaxableIncome, LessTE, LessPPH, NetTax, TaxDue, HeldTaxCE, HeldTaxPE, TotalTax, TIN, From, To) " +
"VALUES(@ID, @First, @Last, @Gross, @LessTNT, @TCI, @ADDTI, @GTI, @LessTE, @LessPPH, @LessNTI, @TD, @TWCE, @TWPE, @TATW, @TIN, @From, @To)";
```

And now it's returning a very unhelpful error: Syntax ERROR in INSERT INTO. That's really all it says.

Here's the rest of the code for your analysis. If I remove the from and to, it works perfectly.

```
OleDbConnection Dbcon = new OleDbConnection(Con);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO ACTB (ID, FirstName, LastName, GrossIncome, LessTNT, TaxableIncomeCE, TaxableIncomePE, GrossTaxableIncome, LessTE, LessPPH, NetTax, TaxDue, HeldTaxCE, HeldTaxPE, TotalTax, TIN, From, To) " +
                    "VALUES(@ID, @First, @Last, @Gross, @LessTNT, @TCI, @ADDTI, @GTI, @LessTE, @LessPPH, @LessNTI, @TD, @TWCE, @TWPE, @TATW, @TIN, @From, @To)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", txtFirst.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", txtLast.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gross", Convert.ToDouble(txtGross.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessTNT", Convert.ToDouble(txtLessTNT.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCI", Convert.ToDouble(txtTCI.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDTI", Convert.ToDouble(txtADDTI.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GTI", Convert.ToDouble(txtGTI.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessTE", Convert.ToDouble(txtLessTE.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessPPH", Convert.ToDouble(txtLessPPH.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessNTI", Convert.ToDouble(txtLessNTI.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TD", Convert.ToDouble(txtTD.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TWCE", Convert.ToDouble(txtTWCE.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TWPE", Convert.ToDouble(txtTWPE.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TATW", Convert.ToDouble(txtTATW.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIN", txtTIN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", txtFrom.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", txtTo.Text);
Dbcon.Open();
cmd.Connection = Dbcon;

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I've double checked the data source view, and my Access database is indeed the updated one, so the fields should exist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "From" and "To" are reserved words, so you cannot use them to name your fields.

Please, try with FromField and ToField names, to make it work.

Comment: This worked, Thankyou! I keep forgetting about reserved words, both SQL and C#!